# How to loop only internal html/dom/content using ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

I want to loop li with different condition and apply different html depending on that condition.

If i code this way

```
<ul ng-repeat="item in items">

   <li ng-if="item == '1'">
    <div><span> <span>My test 123</span>
    {{item }}
    </span></div>
   </li> 
   <li ng-if="item == '2'">
    <div><span class="xyz"> <span class="abc">My new test XXX</span>
    {{item }}
    </span>
     <span>123</span>
    </div>
   </li> 
</ul>
```

It repeat as

```
 <ul ng-repeat="item in items">
   <li>My test 123 
      1</li> 
</ul>
 <ul ng-repeat="item in items">
   <li>
     My new test XXX
   2    123</li> 
</ul>
```

But i want

```
 <ul ng-repeat="item in items">
   <li>My test 123 
      1</li> 
   <li>
     My new test XXX
   2    123</li>  
</ul>
```

Any solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeat on the DOM element you want repeated?

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item }}</li> 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul >
   <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item }}</li> 
</ul>
```